# Selecting a result and using in another select

Tags: sql, select, nested

I want to know if there is a way to do something like this.

```
select outsidecolumn, example1, example2
from (
    select exemple1,example2 
    from tablenames 
    inner joins
    where conditions) as p,
    table2 tb
    where p.example1 = tb.outsidecolumn
```

Comment: It is. Use table aliases when providing result-set columns in your select clause. But instead of having a cross join you could likely do better without the subquery and just use everyday inner/outer joins. **Or** you could as well use CTEs to provide your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select tb.outsidecolumn, p.example1, p.example2
from 
(
  select exemple1,example2 
  from tablenames 
  inner joins
  where conditions
) p
inner join table2 tb
  on p.example1 = tb.outsidecolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative appropach - CTE

And also `inner join` instead of cartesian although execution plan will likely be the same, but is **arguably** more readable.

```
with p as (
    select exemple1,example2 
    from tablenames 
    inner joins
    where conditions
)
select tb.outsidecolumn, p.example1, p.example2
from p
    join table2 tb
    on tb.outsidecolumn = p.example1
```